LINQ to SQL null coalasce not working as intended
When I use a null coalescing operator in the ".Where" section of a linq statement, it's not working as intended.
Here's the offending code: (Note that the TotalBalance is of type nullable decimal.)
Account.Where(n => (n.TotalBalance ?? 0) != 0)
.Select(n => new { n.AccountId, n.TotalBalance })

The result includes accounts whose TotalBalance is null:

Checking the SQL generated by LINQ to SQL, I can see the problem:
SELECT [n].[AccountID], [n].[TotalBalance]
FROM [Account] AS [n]
WHERE (COALESCE([n].[TotalBalance], 0.0) <> 0.0) OR [n].[TotalBalance] IS NULL

Why is LINQ to SQL inserting the condition OR [n].[TotalBalance] IS NULL?
If I remove the null coalesce from the linq statement, the results are correct:
Account.Where(n=>n.TotalBalance != null && n.TotalBalance != 0)
.Select(n => new { n.AccountId, n.TotalBalance })


Using EF Core version 2.2.6 (yes, I know it's deprecated.  Is that a known bug that was fixed?)

so you try to compare decimal/float with integer? did you try to cast to decimal and compare with 0.0M ?

here working example https://dotnetfiddle.net/QkssGo

Yes, @PowerMouse, comparing using 0.0M yields the same results:  .Where(n => (n.TotalBalance ?? 0.0M) != 0.0M)

did you see example? public decimal? xxx. https://dotnetfiddle.net/UA7B1S i add another condition

Yes, I see it's working in your example.  Apparently LINQ to SQL is working differently than straight LINQ, as shown in your example.  Thank you for the example!

maybe its time to update EF to higher version?

It is the wrong way to do it anyway, any index on TotalBalance would not be usable if is wrapped in a COALESCE function inside the where.

LINQ-to-SQL is not EF. If you use Linqpad you may use LINQ-to-SQL if you don't connect to the EF context. The generated SQL seems to come from EF though. Anyway, if it was an issue in 2.2, it's not in 8.0 any more. But, as Magnus said, a better query shape is Where(n => n.TotalBalance.HasValue && n.TotalBalance != 0). That is a sargable expression.

@GertArnold, thanks for clarifying EF versus LINQ to SQL.  I think you're right -- EF is translating from LINQ to SQL.  Bonus points for using a great word: "sargable."

It's been a long time since EFC 2, so it is virtually impossible to track all the bugs that were introduced in some version and fixed in another. What you can try though is to enable relational nulls handling - I think this was from the very first EFC version and basically turns off the attempts to emulate C# null comparison semantics which are different from SQL. e.g. .UseSqlServer(Your_Connection_String, o => o.UseRelationalNulls(true))
